# How can i create an elevation like this in three.js

Tags: three.js

I am building an earth mesh, but instead of a bump map, I want the surface to look like (the picture below).

Can someone please help me. What do I do?

[image]

Comment: You could extrude a shape: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html and https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check out displacement maps or height maps. They manipulate the actual geometry of the mesh, creating real bumps where normal/bump maps only "fake" them.

To create something like in that picture I believe you will need a sphere with a large amount of vertices, since the elevation in image look very detailed.

I hope this was helpful, good luck!